# Jquery Tag-IT Allow Comma in the Middle

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tag-it

Ok so here's the thing. We are using the 3rd party control "tag-it" on our controls.
[JQUERY TAG-IT](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)

Now we have an issue wherein we need to allow the user to paste two word text then put a comma in between. To demonstrate this is the current behavior of the tag-it control:

1. User paste "text sample"
2. User puts comma in the middle "text , sample"
3. Jquery tag-it tags the word as "text sample"

the behavior that i want is this:

1. User paste "text sample"
2. User puts comma in the middle "text , sample"
3. Jquery tag-it tags the words as "text" and "sample"

Is this possible and if yes how could we implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the `tag-it.js` if you are not using the minified one.
Find line 224, and before that line paste this block of code :

```
this.tagInput.bind('paste', function (event) {
    // Set short timeout so .val() will have a value
    setTimeout(function () {
        var tagArray = that.tagInput.val().split(/[\n,]+/);
        if (tagArray.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tagArray.length; i++) {
                that.createTag(tagArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

So basically what it does is to bind a new paste event and split input by comma, and for separated item, a new tag was created.

Please refer to this github issue :
https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/301

You welcome :) ---> You're welcome... Hahahaha.

**QUESTION**
How about if you're not pasting the values and just manually typed the comma?

**EDIT 2: Another Option**

1. Revert all the changes i done before.
2. Remove line 244, `(event.which === $.ui.keyCode.COMMA && event.shiftKey === false) ||`

This is to allow comma in input

3. Modify line 270 to check if there is a comma in the input

   ```
   that.tagInput.autocomplete('close');
   if ($.trim(that.tagInput.val()).indexOf(',') > -1) {
       var tagArray = that.tagInput.val().split(/[\n,]+/);
       if (tagArray.length > 1) {
           for (var i = 0; i < tagArray.length; i++) {
               that.createTag($.trim(tagArray[i]));
           }
       }
   }
   else {
       that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());
   }
   ```

   Explanation: 
   Since we allowed spaces (I assumed) and also allow commas, the only trigger now  to create tags is by pressing enter key.

So for example: 
Input: "Sample, Text"
After I press Enter key, it will be separated into "Sample" and "Text" tags.

Comment: Hi Katana, Appreciate the suggestion. But the issue is typing the comma manually in a middle of  two words. Not copy pasting it having a comma already.

Comment: 2. User puts comma in the middle "text , sample" <--- its already there.

Comment: @TheProvost glad it helps!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, except I don't want commas to split tags. I want commas to be a part of the tag. The infuriating part is that it works locally and in dev, but not prod...